# MySQL simple query syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

When I try to run this simple script:

```
INSERT INTO landlord (full_name, tel_number, email, password) VALUES
  ('landlord1', '12345', 'landlord1@email.com', 'pass1'),
  ('landlord2', '12345', 'landlord2@email.com', 'pass2'),
  ('landlord3', '12345', 'landlord3@email.com', 'pass3');
```

I got an error:

```
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO landlord (full_name, tel_number, email, password) VALUES
  ('landlor' at line 2
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: It does seem simple -- nothing appears wrong to me. Could you post output of `DESCRIBE landlord` ?

Comment: The problem might be hidden characters that you cannot see at the end of the first line or beginning of the second.

Comment: weird, when I try to describe landlord, I've got the same error.
This script i run from IntelliJ IDEA. But when I run it from MySQL Workbench - everything works.

Comment: Guys thank you all, I had SQL Server dialect instead of MySQL.